# Keep track of the most recent constructed object

Tags: javascript

I have this constructor that I'll call "Test" here. My problem is that I can't keep track of its most recent construction. What I mean is that I want to be able to know the last constructed instance of a Test using a property such as lastSeen.

Here is an example:

```
var Test = function(obj1,obj2){
  this.lastSeen = //This is where i dont know where to keep track of it
}

var testing = new Test("Hi", "I'm testing");
if(testing === Test.lastSeen) return "Success" // This should work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `this` inside your constructor is the newly created instance.

You can attach your most recently created instance to the constructor from within using `Test.lastSeen = this;`.

```
var Test = function(obj1,obj2){
  Test.lastSeen = this; // Stash a reference on constructor.
}

var testing = new Test("Hi", "I'm testing");
if(testing === Test.lastSeen) return "Success" // This will work.
```

Comment: That actually makes sense and was completely eluding me. Thank you so much.

Comment: If I wanted to say print out my objects how would I go about doing that. I tried doing something like the following: Test.prototype.print = function(){ print(obj1 + obj2)}, but this doesnt work.

Comment: In most contexts `console.log` is the `print` of JS.

Comment: I understand console.log would be the preferred method, but even replacing that I get two undefined printed out which doesn't make sense. I thought I should be able to  access obj1 and obj2 as long as i used the this keyword:

Comment: Ah, you'll also need to reference the instance variables via `this`. Like: `console.log(this.obj1, this.obj2)`. You'll need to attach them to the instance in your constructor, too. They're unused (discarded) in your example above. We're getting pretty far from the original question here. :)

Comment: Yea, I am sorry about that. The thing is I did exactly that I got undefined, but its fine I'll just fiddle with my code. Appreciate all the help so far.